# I am getting Error "list has more than 1 row for assignment to sobject" while executing approval process in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger MyTestTrigger on Case (before update,after update){           
    if(trigger.isbefore && trigger.isupdate){        
        // This method will call the first approval process ,it's working as expected and in Final approval action after update trigger will be calling 
        GSCaseApprovals.primarymethod(trigger.new,trigger.oldmap);         
    }

    if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isupdate){                
        if(GSUtility.approverrecurioncheck){            
            GSCaseApprovals.opsapprovalprocess(trigger.new,trigger.oldmap);            
            GSUtility.approverrecurioncheck = False;            
        }

        if(GSUtility.finappcheck && (trigger.new[0].GS_Case_Sub_Status__c == 'Pending Finance Approval' && trigger.new[0].LS_Engage_Date_Ordered__c == 'Finance Approval Invoked' && trigger.new[0].status == 'Closed')){            
            //GSCaseApprovals.financeapprovalprocess(JSON.serialize(trigger.new),JSON.serialize(trigger.oldmap));                                     
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();            
            req2.setComments('Submitting request for approval automatically using Trigger');            
            req2.setObjectId(trigger.new[0].id);            
            req2.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('GS_Case_Fin_Approval_Process');            
            //req2.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);

            try{
                // Here i am getting error trigger MyTestTrigger on Case (before update,after update) {                                                
                if(trigger.isbefore && trigger.isupdate){                    
                    system.debug('>>>>>>.before - update<<<<<<<< ');                    
                    GSCaseApprovals.primarymethod(trigger.new,trigger.oldmap);                     
                }

                if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isupdate){                    
                    system.debug('>>>>>>.after - update<<<<<<<< ');                    

                    if(GSUtility.approverrecurioncheck){                        
                        GSCaseApprovals.opsapprovalprocess(trigger.new,trigger.oldmap);                       
                        GSUtility.approverrecurioncheck = False;                       
                    }

                    if(GSUtility.finappcheck && (trigger.new[0].GS_Case_Sub_Status__c == 'Pending Finance Approval' && trigger.new[0].LS_Engage_Date_Ordered__c == 'Finance Approval Invoked' && trigger.new[0].status == 'Closed')){                        
                        //GSCaseApprovals.financeapprovalprocess(JSON.serialize(trigger.new),JSON.serialize(trigger.oldmap));                                                                         
                        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();                     
                        req2.setComments('Submitting request for approval automatically using Trigger');                        
                        req2.setObjectId(trigger.new[0].id);                        
                        req2.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('GS_Case_Fin_Approval_Process');                        
                        //req2.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);                                                

                        try{
                            // Here i am getting list has more than 1 row for assignment to sobject error, i have tried with bulky using list even i am getting same error.                            
                            Approval.ProcessResult results = Approval.process(req2);                         
                        }catch(dmlexception e){                            
                            system.debug('>>>>>exception message is<<<<< '+e.getmessage());                            
                            system.debug('>>>>>exception error is<<<<< '+e);

                            trigger.new[0].adderror('This record is not satisfying for finance approval process there is some data wrong in the record');                            
                        }                                                                                                                        
                        GSUtility.finappcheck = False;                        
                    }                    
                }
                Approval.ProcessResult results = Approval.process(req2);                
            }catch(dmlexception e){                
                system.debug('>>>>>exception message is<<<<< '+e.getmessage());                
                system.debug('>>>>>exception error is<<<<< '+e);

                trigger.new[0].adderror('This record is not satisfying for finance approval process there is some data wrong in the record');                
            }                                                            
            GSUtility.finappcheck = False;            
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are adding a new record to `Trigger.New` or `Trigger.Old` in one of your other methods.  This will cause an error if you attempt to pass the `List<sObject>` as a parameter in to a method which takes an `sObject` - if `List.size() == 1`, this will behave like `List[0]`, but otherwise it will either throw an error about the `List` being empty or the error you are seeing.

In any case, I would recommend that you [bulkify](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Bulkify_Your_Code) your code regardless - you never know when you're going to be running this against multiple objects at once.

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly help if you sent us the code where the exception ocurrs, since I don't think that would be it. It must be within one of the helper methods.

Generally that ocurrs when you try to set a variable with a list. Make sure you are don't have anything like this in your code:

```
SObject myObj = trigger.new;
```

Or any other list, for the record.

This is a very typical exception when you try to save a query's result in a variable and forget to type the `LIMIT 1`, for example.

Nonetheless, as said, check the stack trace thoroughly and see in which class, method and line the exception is being thrown, so you can fix it.